# Hyperlink Label text is not showing mouse Hand cursor after hovering on it in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am using **CustomRenderer** to make the Label text as the hyperlink. With my code Label is showing Underlined and we are using **Label.GestureRecognizers** to capture the click. But the mouse cursor is not showing Hand after hovering on the hyperlink text.

Below is the code that we are using:

**Shared Project:**

- HyperlinkLabel.cs:

```cs
namespace HyperlinkLabelControl
{
     public class HyperLinkLabel : Label
     {
     }
}
```

- MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HyperlinkLabelControl"
             x:Class="HyperlinkLabelControl.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <local:HyperlinkLabel Text="MyHyperLinkLabel" >
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Command="{Binding BindingContext.MyClickedCommand, Source={x:Reference List}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </local:HyperlinkLabel>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**UWP Project:**

- HyperLinkLabelRenderer.cs:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HyperLinkLabel), typeof(HyperLinkLabelRenderer))]
namespace HyperlinkLabelControl.UWP.Renderers
{
    public class HyperLinkLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
                Control.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
        }
    }
}
```

Please provide the approach with that the Mouse Cursor will show Hand after hovering on Hyperlink Text in Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hyperlink Label text is not showing mouse Hand cursor after hovering on it in Xamarin

The problem is  the `Hyperlink` was not passed to `TextBlock.Inlines`. And `Underline` enumeration is only provide under line text style. You could add the `Hyperlink` like the follow in the `HyperLinkLabelRenderer` class.

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (Control != null)
    {
        Control.Inlines.Clear();
        var hl = new Hyperlink();
        hl.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = Element.Text });
        Control.Inlines.Add(hl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nico Zhu, It works for me. One more thing here Can I copy the text of this Hyperlink Label?

Comment: Copy the text? which text? url or display text?

Comment: You could use this property  `Control.IsTextSelectionEnabled = true`.

Comment: Zhu: I want to copy the Display Text of Label. The property Control.IsTextSelectionEnabled is not allowing me to select the Label Text.

Comment: One more thing, What is the best way to handle the Clicked event on HyperLink of Text?

Comment: `HyperLink` often used to open a link, if you want this, you add `Uri` to `Hyperlink`. If you want to do other thing you could use `TapGestureRecognizer` just like you used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172939/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-ankit-jain).

Comment: The TapGestureRecognizer will not work on Hyperlink, the Click event should work. But we are following MVVM architecture and having multiple hyperlink columns, So we need to find another approach for it.

Comment: Ok, Please create  new  thread and let me know . I will check.